# How to open hyperlink from a cell and save/rename downloaded file from new cell value?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a table of links. I want to open each link (they are .csv/.xlsx files on a secure server which I have to login to), then saveas with a file name generated by information in Column (C), to keep the BatchID intact.

```
|     A      |      B       |    C     | 
| Batch Date | links        | New name | 
|------------|--------------|----------|
| 3/03/2014  | View         | 20140303 |
| 2/05/2014  | View         | 20140205 |
| 1/02/2014  | View         | 20140102 |
| 12/01/2013 | View         | 20131201 |
| 11/01/2013 | View         | 20131101 |
| 10/01/2013 | View         | 20131001 |
| 9/01/2013  | View         | 20130901 |
| 8/01/2013  | View         | 20130801 |
```

The links may popup at login (that's ok, I have the credentials, though if using VBA it would be safer to hard code that in so if I miss a popup it won't stall).

The list is extensive and is updated monthly.
The original csv/.xlsx filename is similar:
**1036548025_detailed_sales_report.xls** the number always differs (hence the new column above), however the **_detailed_sales_report.xls** remains static.

I would ideally like to keep the filename by using a wildcard. So something like:
`savefilename = (A10) & "*" & "_detailed_sales_report.xls"`

I googled opening hyperlinks from Excel but most of it is either about hyperlinks in general or opening a linked workbook, whereas I want to download new work.

There needs to be a delay between each row, the server is slow.

Each link is newly generated. No link is the same (like the file name):

```
    Range("C9").Select
      Selection.Hyperlinks(1).Follow NewWindow:=False, AddHistory:=True
        Workbooks.Open Filename:="http://www.mylinkgoeshere.---/.php?pID=12898"
            'the pID= is always different, its a dynamic report system

        ActiveWindow.Visible = False
        Windows("view_payment_orders.php").Visible = True
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="D:\location\20140205.xlsx", _
        FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
        ActiveWorkbook.Save
    ActiveWindow.Close
```

The above is what happens when I run the Macro recorder, I don't want to have to code in over 100+ lines. Can a loop work between two columns?

Comment: why open just to save as with different name? Can you just rename? or copy the file and rename it?

Comment: They aren't on my system, they are downloaded via hyperlink, and with over 50 (last count was 120 of them) at a time I don't want to do it manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't possibly simulate the links you're opening but you can try this:

```
Sub test()

Dim hlink As Hyperlink
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim saveloc As String

saveloc = "D:\location\"
For Each hlink In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("NameOfYourSheet").Hyperlinks
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(hlink.Address)
    wb.SaveAs saveloc & hlink.Parent & ".xlsx"
    wb.Close True
    Set wb = Nothing
Next

End Sub
```

I assumed that Excel can open the files in your link directly just using the address.
What above code does is loop through all hyperlinks in your target sheet.
`hlink.Address` gets the address and then use it in `Workbooks.Open` method.
You then save it as `.xlsx` file using the `hlink.Parent` as filename.
`hlink.Parent` returns the hyperlinked word.
To complete the *save as path*, we initialized the file location `saveloc`.
This is **tried** and **tested** but only on links I created which are in my local drive.

**Edit1:** To save using the hyperlink's adjacent cell value.

```
For Each hlink In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("NameOfYourSheet").Hyperlinks
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(hlink.Address)
    wb.SaveAs saveloc & hlink.Range.Offset(0,1).Value & ".xlsx"
    wb.Close True
    Set wb = Nothing
Next
```

`hlink.Range` returns a `Range Object` where the hyperlink is.
We use `Offset` property to get to the adjacent cell and then get it's value for the filename.

Comment: that looks great, thank you!  Is there a way for it to pick up the name from `Column C`, or at least a way I can make the `hlink.parent` be overwritten by my specs in `Column C`, I need to keep the BatchID intact cleanly.

Comment: Thank you!  You just saved me countless hours of work!  Now the hard part ..  lol compiling.  Thank you! :-)