# Excel VBA Listbox links

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007, excel-2010

I currently have a macro with two columns and many rows. The two columns holds info such as First name and a link to a folder or website.

When i click the button on the macro, it takes all the info from the excel sheet and shows the first name and places it in a listbox.

I was wondering, is it possible that when i click the button, i displays the first name in the listbox but also stores a link? when i select an item in the listbox, i want it to open up the link. is this possible?

i have thought of one way, and that is with the listbox and an array which stores the link, and when i click on an item, it searches the array and then opens the link, FOR EXMAPLE: if i click the first item in the listbox, it will go into the array and go to array(1) and then get that link.

That is one way i thought of but is there an easier way? rather than i storing the link into an array and all that.

the current code that i have is:

```
For row = 3 To 10
    ListBox1.AddItem Range("A" & row).Text
Next
```

i don't know how to add a hyperlink to this code

Comment: What is your existing code?

Comment: is it UserForm listbox?

Comment: Yes, it is a userform listbox

Comment: You can iterate through all hyperlink and then use the `.FollowHyperlink` method.

Comment: [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662795/vba-or-formula-to-open-hyperlink-from-a-cell-and-save-rename-downloaded-file-f/22677564#22677564) is how to iterate or manipulate hyperlinks. Then it's up to youif you use `Workbooks.Open` method or `.FollowHyperlink` for links to non-Excel files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:**

What I would do is create `Listbox` with two columns:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim row As Integer

    ListBox1.ColumnCount = 2
    ListBox1.ColumnWidths = "50;150"
    For row = 3 To 10
        ListBox1.AddItem Range("A" & row).Text
        ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 1) = Range("B" & row).Text
    Next
End Sub
```

Here is `ListBox1_DblClick` handler (when user double clicked on listbox item):

```
Private Sub ListBox1_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Address:=ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListIndex, 1)
ExitHere:
    Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
    If Err.Number = -2147221014 Then
        MsgBox "Wrong link!"
    Else
        MsgBox "Error: " & Err.Description
    End If
    Resume ExitHere
End Sub
```

Then you can double click on any item in listbox to follow hyperlink:

[image]

Also I suggest you to change `Range("A" & row).Text` to `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & row).Text`

Comment: is it possible that instead of hiding the second column with the hyperlink, i make it visible and when users click on the link, it opens up the link?

Comment: yes, it's possible, do you already have any code that opens link?

Comment: No, i currently do not have any code that will open up links in this macro

Comment: Plus one. But you can actually work on the hyperlink object so you wouldn't worry links that doesn't use the actual links address as display text in cells.

Comment: @L42, thanks, do you mean to iterate through all hyperlinks like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662795/vba-or-formula-to-open-hyperlink-from-a-cell-and-save-rename-downloaded-file-f/22677564#22677564)? It's a good point, but I would leave this implementation for OP:)

Comment: Cool :p I posted that in OP's question :)

Comment: Hey @simoco, is there something missing in the private sub? it is giving me an error

Comment: When i try to double click, i get a error message saying, "wrong link" and then the next errors will say "Error: file name or class name not found during automation operation"

Comment: it seems that your link is indeed wrong. Can you show me your link?

Comment: @simoco i changed the links to "https:// www.google.ca" and now they work, thank you very much! you are the best!