# Excel 2010 Download CSV with dynamic name from secure website

Tags: php, excel, vba, csv, web-scraping

I am wanting to login to a site, navigate to a page, then download the `.CSV` file that will always end with a dynamic string due to it being 'custom'.

I have tried to access the site by recording a macro.  However, as the data is not in a table the macro recorder is not able to pick up the actual address of the .csv file.

The display text is always:

```
Results [link]Click to Download[/link]
```

The html values are always:

```
<td class="smallText"><b>Results</b> <a href="vendor_report.php?report=custom [insert extremely long string here] ><u>Click to Download</u></a></td>
```

Without using a table, is there a way to get to this .csv & save it to my PC?
I am aware that the use of `<td>` denotes it is part of a table, but it is definitely not picking it up, I've gone through the site using the macro recorder and it's not picking up the inner contents from the page.
https://[domain].php?vf=vieworders

I had also thought to navigate to the site page, highlight the text, copy & paste to a spare sheet in my book, then use some code [L42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2685412/l42) previously wrote [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22677564/2337102) (below) however I can't even get the copy & paste to work correctly.

```
For Each hlink In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("NameOfYourSheet").Hyperlinks
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(hlink.Address)
    wb.SaveAs saveloc & hlink.Range.Offset(0,1).Value & ".xlsx"
    wb.Close True
    Set wb = Nothing
Next
```

Please advise. Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE**
I have found which table this is hiding in, `Table 2`.  It is however in the midst of a lot of other text.
When I have copied & pasted the table contents to my sheet, I have problems getting the link to show as it's HTML value so I can then use that with my 2nd option (open links from spreadsheet).
This could be an issue with the original `Get Data` code I am using.

This is how it looks.  The cells either side are filled, as well as that huge chunk of (blanked out) text in `B20`

Could Regex be of use here??

[image: chunky data from web tabledownload]

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the XMLHTTP object with a stream:

```
Sub SO()

Dim objStream As Object, strURL As String

Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
strURL = "vendor_report.php?report=custom [insert extremely long string here]"

With CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
    .Open "GET", strURL, False
    .Send
    If .Status = 200 Then
        objStream.Open
        objStream.Type = 1
        objStream.Write .ResponseBody
        objStream.SaveToFile "C:\users\bloggsj\output.csv", 2
        objStream.Close
    End If
End With

Set objStream = Nothing

End Sub
```

Change the save path as required.

Comment: thank you.  I've been able to navigate to the page using http://bit.ly/1ETIAbl, I then run your code. Your code gets me a new .csv (correct), however it pulls the page data in to it, it doesn't pull the existing .csv down.  The string details past 'custom' do change, could this be the issue?  Many thanks :D